# Expectation of the product implies independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X, Y$ be two random variables that take at most $2$ values, denoted as $a$ and $b$. I am asked to show that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ implies the independence of the variables. I already know that this is not true for any random variable.

I tried writing the random variables as
$$X=a1_{X=a}+b1_{X=b} \ \ \ \ \ Y=a1_{Y=a}+b1_{Y=b}$$

But the fact that $a,b$ are not arbitrary makes me confused. Any hint?

Comment: "Are not arbitrary"? Isn't it part of the point that they *are* arbitrary, here?

Comment: Regardless, what did you try? Applying the definition of independence of random variables?

Comment: I know it is enough to show $P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$, but the equality between the expectations is not enough to guaratee this.

Comment: @Jan Hint: $E[1_{X=m}1_{Y=n}]=P(X=m,Y=n)$

Answer (score 1):

You can write $X=(a-b)+bZ$ and $Y=(a-b)+bW$. Then it suffices to show that $Z,W$ are independent, as $X$ and $Y$ are functions of them, respectively. Note that $Z,W\in\{0,1\}$ and
$$
0=Cov(X,Y)=\frac{(b-a)^2}4 Cov(Z,W)
$$
so $Cov(ZW)=0$ (unless $a=b$ in which case $X$ and $Y$ are independent since they are a.s. constants).

Let $A=\{Z=1\}$ and $B=\{W=1\}$, so $Z=1_A$, $W=1_B$. We have
$$
0=Cov(Z,W)=\mathbb{E}(ZW)-\mathbb{E}(Z)\mathbb{E}(W)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)
$$
so $\mathbb{P}(Z=1,W=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z=1)\mathbb{P}(W=1)$; so the events $A$ and $B$ are independent. Therefore $A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent, $A$ and $B^c$ are independent, $A^c$ and $B$ are independent, which is required to show the independence of the indicator random variables $Z$ and $W$.